# Replicating a complex material with different colors and transparencies varying along its depth

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

I must premise that I am a complete noob when it comes to blender. I come from rendering in V-Ray and wanted to give blender a shot.

I need to make renders of materials composed of various layers in different colors and transparencies. I am not exactly sure how to tackle this.

Any guidance on how to set up materials to do this? Attached is a reference image of an example material.

Below is front view and side view:

[image]

And here is a perspective view of how the material actually looks like in real life:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to recreate in 3D the kind of image you show?

Comment: No, I already have a 3D model done in Rhino3D. I want to use blender as a render engine. I need help in recreating these types of material.